# how to increase performance of onclick popup in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance

I have to open a popup window when I click on a button, it is displaying but taking time. How can I overcome this problem so that it takes less time? I am calling a function when I click on the save button.
     
                                        
                                            Save
                                            Cancel
                                            
                                                Delete

This is the code for the save button. When I click on this button the *lessonsave* function will be called, although it is taking longer than I would like it to.

```
   <div class="col-sm-12 form-group fall-footer" style="margin-top: 35px;">
                                <sapn class="pull-right">
                                    <button type="button" id="refresh" class="btn btn-save" onclick="LessonSave()">Save</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-cancel" id="historyLesson_Cancel">Cancel</button>
                                    <sec:authorize access="@mySecurityService.hasPermissions('delete','46')">
                                        <button type="button" id="h_lessondelete" class="btn btn-save" onclick="HistoryLessonDelete()">Delete</button>
                                    </sec:authorize>
                                </sapn>
                            </div>

   <script>
    function LessonSave() {
        $("#h_cmts").val("");
        $("#h_curriculumtypemodel").modal("show");

    }
</script>
```

Comment: It seems unlikely that the code you have shared would be causing a performance hit. My best guess is that some other code is blocking up the CPU or taking too long. Please update your question with a [Minimum Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help us debug with better context.

Comment: Maybe the `save` process took long.

Comment: hi Sachi Tekina  when i call that function actually popup will open not save method in that popup i had another button for save